# How can I Change the BackgroungResource different time In my #Kotlin app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know it seems that my question had been asking before, but all the questions and the answers were for [java](/questions/tagged/java) but I want it specifically for [[image]kotlin](/questions/tagged/kotlin)!
I have a *drawable.xml* for change the shape and the color of a button
and I have another drawable in it there is a different shape and color.
In different cases, I want to change the *Resource* of a button at different times, but it takes only the first change and after that, it keeps that way!

Comment: Any Java code can be easily converted. Please tell us what you have tried and show us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sequence could be wrong. You should take care of sequence of states in a way that property without any state should come in last like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:color="#ffbb00"/>
    <item android:state_focused="true"
          android:color="#00ffbb"/>
    <item android:color="#ffffff"/> <!-- without any state should come in last -->
</selector>
```

If this do not solve your problem than **Please share your code so I can help more specifally**